# Extract and get value from a text file python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, paramiko

I have executed ssh commands in remote machine using paramiko library and written output to text file. Now, I want to extract few values from a text file. The output of a text file looks as pasted below

```
b'\nMS Administrator\n(C) Copyright 2006-2016 LP\n\n[MODE]> SHOW INFO\n\n\nMode: \nTrusted Certificates\n1 Details\n------------\n\tDeveloper ID: MS-00c1\n\tTester ID: ms-00B1\n\tValid from: 2030-01-29T06:51:15Z\n\tValid until: 2030-01-30T06:51:15Z\n\t
```

how do i get the value of Developer ID and Tester ID. The file is huge.

As suggested by users I have written the snippet below.

```
file = open("Output.txt").readlines()
for lines in file:
    word = re.findall('Developer\sID:\s(.*)\n', lines)[0]
    print(word)
```

I see the error IndexError: list index out of range
If i remove the index. I see empty output

Comment: Use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
file = open("Output.txt").readlines()
developer_id=""

for lines in file:
    if 'Developer ID' in line:                                                                                         
        developer_id = line.split(":")[-1].strip()                                                                     

print developer_id
```

Comment: file = open("Output.txt").readlines()
for lines in file:
    word = re.findall('Developer\sID:\s(.*)\n', str(lines))
    print(word)

Comment: prints empty output

Comment: @louis `file = open("Output.txt").readlines()` will give you list of strings. try `file = open("Output.txt").read() ` then, `re.findall('Developer\sID:\s(.*)\n', file)[0]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still no luck. I see indexerror

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Regular expressions**

```
text = """\nMS Administrator\n(C) Copyright 2006-2016 LP\n\n[MODE]> SHOW INFO\n\n\nMode: \nTrusted Certificates\n1 Details\n------------\n\tDeveloper ID: MS-00c1\n\tTester ID: ms-00B1\n\tValid from: 2030-01-29T06:51:15Z\n\tValid until: 2030-01-30T06:51:15Z\n\t"""
import re
developerID = re.match("Developer ID:(.+)\\n", text).group(0)
testerID = re.match("Tester ID:(.+)\\n", text).group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your output is consistent in format, you can use something as easy as line.split():

```
developer_id = line.split('\n')[11].lstrip()
tester_id = line.split('\n')[12].lstrip()
```

Again, this assumes that every line is using the same formatting.  Otherwise, use regex as suggested above.